# DB2 Alter column type and index state RBDP vs. "needs a rebuild"

Tags: index, db2, alter-table, db2-luw

I'm new to DB2 and databases overall.

I'm building a script to alter several column data types in several tables of which some are part of indexes and some not. So after ALTER-statements I assumed I have to rebuild the indexes. According this [source](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/admin/src/tpc/db2z_whathappenscolumnindex.html):
"When the data type of the ACCTID column is altered from DECIMAL(4,0) to INTEGER, the IX1 index is placed in a REBUILD-pending (RBDP) state."

My  questions:
1. If index is in RBDP state, does it mean it has to be rebuild and how should I return the index to accessible state?
2. How can I find the indexes which are now in RBDP state? I tried this after a altering a column type:

```
SELECT tabname, indname, index_requires_rebuild
FROM TABLE(sysproc.admin_get_index_info('I','','')) AS t
WHERE index_requires_rebuild = 'Y';
```

but I still can't find any indexes requiring a rebuild, so I guess RBDP state and "requires rebuild" are different animals. So what is the difference and how can I be certain the index is still working as it should be after my ALTER statements?

The statements I use are in this form:

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE1 ALTER COLUMN COLUMN1 SET DATA TYPE BIGINT 
GO
CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD('REORG TABLE TABLE1')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you're reading documentation for Db2 on z/OS, but you're running tests on Db2 for Linux, UNIX & Windows.

When you perform this particular alter on Db2 for Linux, UNIX and Windows, it will succeed, but the *table* will be placed immediately into reorg pending state, which you can see in `SYSIBMADM.ADMINTABINFO` (see the `REORG_PENDING` column).  `INDEXES_REQUIRE_REBUILD` will still show as 'N', even though performing a REORG on the table will rebuild the index.

Comment: Hi, thanks you very much for the response. Are you saying that performing the reorg (which I already do) is a sufficient procedure to return the index in working state?

Comment: @JuliusTorkkeli Yes.  Issuing a `REORG` on the table will rebuild the indexes as part of the operation.